# Dell XPS 9550 - 16.04 LTS: black screen on suspend

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, suspend

Dell XPS 9550 (15", 2015) -- 16GB swap, 250GB SDD, 4K

Upon opening my computer from suspending (whether from closing the lid or otherwise) the screen is completely black but the computer is in fact on. When I push the audio function keys, I can hear the audio start/stop and the tone when the audio level changes.

I have sufficient swap space and this started upon installing 16.04. This happens with both the `NVIDIA Binary Driver - version 367.57...(proprietary)` and `X.org X server -- Nouveau display driver` for the GeForce GTX 960M.